# Exception when Exchanging Refresh Token

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I have developed an application for Google calendar integration. I got stuck at one place when I am using the calendar services. Please check the code below.

```
private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg, String Refreshtoken)
{                    
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { CalendarService.Scopes.Calendar.GetStringValue() });
    state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
    state.RefreshToken = Refreshtoken;
    try
    {
        if (arg.RefreshToken(state))     // This is calling out to the OAuth servers with the refresh token getting back a session token, returns true if successful.
        {
            if (state.RefreshToken != Refreshtoken) // if the refresh token has changed, save it.
            {
              //save token
            }
            return state; // Retain the authorization state, this is what will authenticate your calls.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return state;
}
```

the exception that i am getting is

```
Exception:
at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request,         
DirectWebRequestOptions options) at 
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request) at 
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.GetDirectResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest) at 
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(IDirectedProtocolMessage request) at     
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) at 
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request[TResponse](IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) at 
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase.RefreshToken(IAuthorizationState authorization, Nullable`1 
skipIfUsefulLifeExceeds) at GoogleCalendarProvider_V3.GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient 
arg, String Refreshtoken)

Exception Message:
Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response.
```

Comment: actually i have asked the same question previously also. But not getting proper reply on this. actually if i am not doing this arg.RefreshToken(state). then i have to specify service.calendarlist.list() execute before every execution of the code. Means if i want to get the eventid from calendar then i have to run the service.calendarlist.list() before the execution of service.Events.Get(eventid).execute(); i dn'y know why but its seems to be a bug.